# iPhone/iPad Augmented Reality lib3DAR CMMotionManager symbol not found error

Tags: iphone, ipad, accelerometer

I'm currently trying to get the **3DAR library** (http://spotmetrix.com/documentation) to work with the latest iphone/ipad ios but when I've followed the exact instructions and use the latest github version of the panoramic example (http://github.com/pmark/Panoramic) I keep getting 2 errors:

- **First error** is about a missing
  "**SM3DAR_keys.txt**" file in the /3DAR
  folder => **fixed** by putting empty SM3DAR_keys.txt file in the folder
- **Second error** is an symbol not found
  error

> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CMMotionManager", referenced from:
>
> ```
>   objc-class-ref-to-CMMotionManager in lib3DAR_v4_0_1.a(SM3DAR_Controller.o)
>
>   ld: symbol(s) not found
>
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
> ```

Anybody has any experience with the package or any idea for suggestion/alternative?

Thanks!
Warm greetings, Thys Bernolet

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What version of iOS are you using? CMMotionManager was introduced in iOS 4.

If you are running iOS 4, check if CoreMotion.framework is listed in frameworks section of your XCode project.

Kay